# How do i add a link to Fancybox to download a hi res version of the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I would like to use fancybox to open a lo-res image in a modal window with the option to download a hi-res version of the same image from a link within the same window.
I have tried this:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterLoad: function() {
        this.title = '<a href="' + this.href + '">Download</a> ' + this.title;
    },
    helpers : {
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    }
});
```

From this jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/zAe6Z/
But it seems to open the same image as is in the window.

Comment: Works as described. `_s.jpg` is the preview image that is used in the list, while `_b.jpg` is both used by fancybox and as download source.

Comment: you need 3 images: thumbnail - shown on your page, medium - to be opened in fancybox and high res - to link from within fancybox's title

Comment: I am using a text link to open the medium pic, that is no problem, the issue i have is that I am have multiple download links from different pics. I have the first .zip download as the href in the Javascript but need to know how to link to each different one.

Comment: Here is the url: [Link to website](http://uraniumdrivein.com/press.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your links seem to follow a pattern :

```
http://uraniumdrivein.com/img/press/press_web/Ayngel_Overson_BW_web.jpg 
http://uraniumdrivein.com/img/press/download/Ayngel_Overson_BW.jpg.zip

http://uraniumdrivein.com/img/press/press_web/Ayngel_Overson_Color_web.jpg
http://uraniumdrivein.com/img/press/download/Ayngel_Overson_Color.jpg.zip

http://uraniumdrivein.com/img/press/press_web/Bette_Nickle_Uravan_web.jpg
http://uraniumdrivein.com/img/press/download/Bette_Nickle_Uravan.jpg.zip
```

The first, to open the image in fancybox (the `href` attribute) and the second to download the high resolution image (in fancybox `title`)

What you can do is to *replace* `press_web` by `download` AND `_web.jpg` by `.jpg.zip` from the opening link into the download link using javascript `replace()` method like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".modal").attr("rel", "gallery").fancybox({
        afterLoad: function () {
            this.title = this.title ?
                '<a href="' + this.href.replace("press_web", "download")
                .replace("_web.jpg", ".jpg.zip") +
                '">Download</a> ' + this.title 
            :
                '<a href="' + this.href.replace("press_web", "download")
                .replace("_web.jpg", ".jpg.zip") +
                '">Download</a>';
        },
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: 'inside'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AfEZZ/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an additional attribute to  tag `target="_blank"` this way:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterLoad: function() {
        this.title = '<a href="' + this.href + '" target="_blank">Download</a> ' + this.title;
    },
    helpers : {
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    }
});
```

Also in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zAe6Z/990/).